# Once they thought that I am a hoax - What am I?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Once they thought that I am a hoax. I am venomous and I can detect electric fields. What am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be a

> Platypus

Because

> Scientists first thought recovered remains of a platypus was different creatures fused together. They thought it was a hoax. 
>  They have a spur in their hind foot which releases venom into its victim
>  Uses elecrolocation to find its prey

Thoughts

> This answer was given by someone else but was deleted due to inadequate (zero) reasoning for proving their answer.

Comment: Yep you got it! The reasoning is correct. I did see the previous answer, but there was no reasoning for it.

Comment: K. I was hoping they would fix it, but I guess it's too late now.

Answer (score 3):

You could be a

> **chimeara**

because it could either mean

> a [certain mythological creature](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chimera_(mythology)) or an organism made by mutating two or more genus,

or

> a [certain fish](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chimaera) that could detect electricity.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are

> Corona

Reasons:

> Trump's speech: https://www.politico.com/news/2020/02/28/trump-south-carolina-rally-coronavirus-118269
>  Venomous: Yeah Corona virus is really venomous!
>  Detect electric fields: Corona discharge https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona_discharge